# GCS gcloud too much passphrase

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud

I'm trying to script my VM creation and setup process.

Currently the script asks for my ssh passphrase multiple times.

Is there a way to enter the passphrase once at the beginning of the script and be done?

here's the first script:

```
gcloud -q compute instances create $VM_NAME \
--zone=$ZONE \
--machine-type=n1-standard-1 \
--image-project=ml-images \
--image-family=tf-1-14 \
--scopes=cloud-platform \
--boot-disk-size=24GB \
&& \
echo vm created \
&& \
gcloud -q compute scp --recurse \
~/altered-source/ $VM_NAME:~ \
--zone=$ZONE \
&& \
gcloud -q compute scp --recurse \
~/vm-scripts/ $VM_NAME:~ \
--zone=$ZONE \
&& \
echo files transfered \
&& \
gcloud -q compute ssh $VM_NAME \
--zone=$ZONE
```

Answer (score 0):

Please provide some details of how you're attempting this.

By default, if you using `gcloud`, an ssh keypair will be generated automatically for you and stored in the metadata service so that you can ssh seamlessly, e.g.

```
gcloud compute instances create ${INSTANCE} ...

gcloud compute ssh ${INSTANCE} ... --command=....
```

Possible a better method to recreate the instance(s) programmatically, is to developer a startup script and then pass this to the instance during creation:

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create#startup-script

Comment: sure the script I'm talking about looks like this ```gcloud -q compute instances create $VM_NAME \
--zone=$ZONE \
--machine-type=n1-standard-1 \
--image-project=ml-images \
--image-family=tf-1-14 \
--scopes=cloud-platform \
--boot-disk-size=24GB \
&& \
echo vm created \
&& \
gcloud -q compute scp --recurse \
~/altered-source/ $VM_NAME:~ \
--zone=$ZONE \
&& \
gcloud -q compute scp --recurse \
~/vm-scripts/ $VM_NAME:~ \
--zone=$ZONE \
&& \
echo files transfered \
&& \
gcloud -q compute ssh $VM_NAME \
--zone=$ZON```

Comment: I've tried using a startup script but google hasn't implemented a way to reference ```cloudshell``` form inside the vm (in the works supposedly). For the moment I have to copy the files while in ```cloudshell``` and run a second script after ssh-ing into the vm.

Comment: Ah, you didn't mention that additional requirement (and your other question) in this question :-) Hmmm.... I discourage you from binding VMs together in this way. It may be better to use a service like Google Cloud Storage as a go-between rather than tightly couple your VMs. IIUC your Cloud Shell instance is generating some set of files that you then wish to copy to (one of more?) VMs. You could copy the files from the Cloud Shell instance to a GCS bucket. Then, from the destination instance copy the files from the GCS bucket.

Answer (score 0):

Yo!
Definitively, use a Storage Bucket for that intra-transfer thing; you'll see you'll have better control and faster responses all the way.

If you really require to use a "third leg" perhaps using your local machine could work, you just need to install the SDK and use gcloud commands, it wont ask you for keys once you exchanged them between local and remote VMs, the caveat? you rely on your ISP Up/Down speeds, the good thing you know what, and how long is taking a file to upload.

Now, once again I suggest as other here already did, use a cloud bucket, that way you only need to refer your file as gs:///file and forget about the rest.

In any case [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/transfer-files) is some info about transferring files to instances.

Have an awesome day!
 -JP